# Is there a good yacc/bison type LALR parser generator for .NET?

Tags: .net, yacc, lalr

Is there a good yacc/bison type LALR parser generator for .NET ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Antlr](http://antlr.org/) supports C# code generation, though it is LL(k) not technically LALR.  Its tree rewriting rules are an interesting feature though.

Answer (score 5):

[SableCC](http://sablecc.org/) can generate c# code. It's pretty good but you need a few days to figure out how it all works, because the documentation ist not that great

Answer (score 3):

The [Gardens Point Parser Generator](http://plas.fit.qut.edu.au/gppg/) looks good, however I've not had a chance to try it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Gold](http://goldparser.org/grammars/index.htm). It is LALR compliant and supports lots of languages, if not the most. Gold can convert YACC and Bison type grammars.

If it does not suit your needs then check out [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators).

Spirit is another LALR parser.

Also note that [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) created a variant of the Jay parser for their c# and .NET framework. Their c# compiler is, from what I can tell, production quality.

Answer (score 0):

[Coco](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Coco/) It's LL(k) but does a good job